# ios passbook kind of animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, passbook

I am trying to implement passbook kind of animation , but not the shredder one. I want a vertical  lists of views which animate up and down when the user touches down. A few lines of sample code will be good

Comment: The way the passbook app animates its passes is highly complex - it's not "a few lines of sample code", it's a *lot* more involved. It's a highly customised app that doesn't use a standard table view.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a video on UIKit Dynamics at WWDC 2013 that described some of how they did that.